# Edit buffer while keeping Helm results open

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

Is it possible to visit a buffer from the result list of Helm while keeping the Helm buffer open? Or is there some other way of achieving the same effect?

I often need to do tasks that involve searching some files, and visit each of them, but the way it works now I have to redo the search everytime I'm done visiting a buffer.

EDIT: FWIW, if using spacemacs, `SPC r l` is bound to `helm-resume`

Comment: What do you mean by "*some other way of achieving the same effect*"? What is the effect? I.e., just what is the need/request? Is it Helm-specific? If not, can it be stated simply as "*searching some files, and edit each of them*" without exiting search?

Comment: I think a more accurate version would be "search some files, and visit a result without exiting search"

Comment: I've edited your question to reflect that clarification, replacing "edit" with "visit". That makes more sense, to me. If you **edit** a buffer then it makes sense that you somehow then need to resume searching ("*redo the search*") when you are done editing it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can revive the last Helm session with the `helm-resume` command (bound by default to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd>). This should effectively achieve what you want.

You can also save the search results to a buffer with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>.

Comment: What is the command's name? I have `C-c b` bound to something else.

Comment: @altschuler: sorry the key combination was wrong. Fixed now and added the respective command.

Answer (score 3):

`helm-follow-mode` will show the results of a helm list while moving the cursor point up and down the helm results list.

For example in Spacemacs, `SPC T s` opens helm with a list of themes, `C-c C-f` activates `helm-follow-mode` and now the themes are applied when navigating up and down the list.

Answer (score 2):

[**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) lets you do this. With [Icicles search](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview) you can navigate among the search hits (across the set of searched buffers or files).

You can cycle among the search hits, but you need not cycle. You can visit any hits you choose, in any order.  You can dynamically filter the hits by typing a filter pattern, which you can change on the fly.

You can combine multiple such dynamic filter patterns, using several simple patterns in place of a more complex one.  Pattern matching can use [apropos](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Apropos_Completions) (regexp) matching or any of several kinds of [fuzzy](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Fuzzy_Completion) matching.  You can also filter by [chipping away](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#ChippingAway) dynamic matches, subtracting them from the current, wider set of matches.

You can even search, not the search contexts you defined at the outset of searching, but their [complement](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview#SearchOutsideContexts).

(Icicles search lets you define the [contexts to search](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview#SearchContext--definition) - for example, only function definitions or only comments. Other text is ignored (not searched). The simplest example is the *lines* of a buffer as search contexts. Line search contexts are what `grep`, `occur`, and `icicle-occur` use.)

You can also [*replace*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search-And-Replace) individual search hits, or the parts of them that match your current input pattern, *on demand*, without exiting Icicles search. And you can change the replacement text anytime during search, on demand.

In the limited sense of such *replacement* you can thus not only visit the searched buffers but *edit* them, without ever exiting search.

Comment: My first thought was "why is there an irrelevant answer about Icicles?". But hey, it sounds pretty good!